# Change mupdf layout under android

Tags: java, android, mupdf

I am trying to adapt Mupdf 1.9 android in order to be able to work with music scores with it. At this point, I want to be able to make annotations with differents colors and pen thicknesses.
I am working from mupdf-1.9a-source/platform/android/viewer/
The basic ink annotation is a big red pen and it is hardcoded in PageView.java (for the drawing part) and mupdf.c (when the drawing is actually validated)

So I modified every functions involved in saving the ink annotation in order to pass the ink color and thickness through all of them.
Now I can choose the color and thickness in MuPDFActivity at compile time and it is passed along to mupdf.c wich uses it.

Obviously, I want to be able to choose the color and thickness whenever I want during execution through the GUI. So I modified the relative layout in res/layout/buttons.xml at line 318 (id: topBar5Accept) and added 2 edittext and adapted the surrounding code (relative positioning) so I could hopefully have those edittext in the top bar during ink annotation.
But now mupdf is crashing at startup.

I can't understand how mupdf for android deals with its topbar. What is ViewAnimator topBarSwitcher? How can I modifiy the topbar in mupdf?
Thanks in advance for your patience.

Here are the part I edited to res/layout/buttons.xml line 318, I added 2 edittext to the relative layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/topBar5Accept"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/toolbar" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/cancelAcceptButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/cancel"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnCancelAcceptButtonClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_cancel" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inkColor"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancelAcceptButton"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/annotType"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="0xFFFF0000"
            android:hint="0xFF00FF00"
        />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/annotType"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/inkColor"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/inkThickness"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/inkThickness"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/annotType"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/acceptButton"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:text="4.0"
            android:hint="5.0"
        />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/acceptButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:contentDescription="@string/accept"
            android:background="@drawable/button"
            android:onClick="OnAcceptButtonClick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_check" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

And here is the logcat when MuPDF is launched:

```
I/Timeline(  877): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.artifex.mupdfdemo time:690956
I/ActivityManager(  548): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.artifex.mupdfdemo/.ChoosePDFActivity} from pid 877
V/Zygote  ( 2677): Switching descriptor 33 to /dev/null
V/Zygote  ( 2677): Switching descriptor 9 to /dev/null
D/dalvikvm( 2677): Late-enabling CheckJNI
I/ActivityManager(  548): Start proc com.artifex.mupdfdemo for activity com.artifex.mupdfdemo/.ChoosePDFActivity: pid=2677 uid=10061 gids={50061, 1028, 1015, 3003}
D/ActivityThread( 2677): handleBindApplication:com.artifex.mupdfdemo
D/ActivityThread( 2677): setTargetHeapUtilization:0.25
D/ActivityThread( 2677): setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
W/Adreno-GSL( 2677): : Android framework reported version 2. So, don't force ES30
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): : EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018_msm8960_KK_2.7_RB1_CL3869936_release_AU (CL3869936)
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: 17.01.10.SPL
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): Build Date: 12/09/13 Mon
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): Local Branch: mybranch2092625
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): Remote Branch: quic/kk_2.7_rb1.15
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): Local Patches: NONE
I/Adreno-EGL( 2677): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_KK_2.7_RB1.04.04.00.007.018 +  NOTHING
D/OpenGLRenderer( 2677): Enabling debug mode 0
D/AndroidRuntime( 2677): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 2677): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41642ce0)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677): Process: com.artifex.mupdfdemo, PID: 2677
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677): java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ChoosePDFAdapter.getView(ChoosePDFAdapter.java:60)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1616)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1717)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1571)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1480)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14841)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1986)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1743)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5603)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:732)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:566)
E/AndroidRuntime( 2677):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
W/ActivityManager(  548):   Force finishing activity com.artifex.mupdfdemo/.ChoosePDFActivity
I/WindowManager(  548): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{41db7840 ActivityRecord{41c725f0 u0 com.artifex.mupdfdemo/.ChoosePDFActivity t16 f}} appWin=Window{41e9b980 u0 com.artifex.mupdfdemo/com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ChoosePDFActivity} drawState=1
W/WindowManager(  548): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for (320x480) to layer 21025
W/ActivityManager(  548): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{41c725f0 u0 com.artifex.mupdfdemo/.ChoosePDFActivity t16 f}
I/Timeline(  877): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41a6f8f0 time:692593
I/Timeline(  548): Timeline: Activity_windows_visible id: ActivityRecord{41cee998 u0 com.cyanogenmod.trebuchet/org.cyanogenmod.trebuchet.CustomHomeLauncher t1} time:692913
I/Process ( 2677): Sending signal. PID: 2677 SIG: 9
W/InputMethodManagerService(  548): Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@41e0fd38 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@41dff268
I/WindowState(  548): WIN DEATH: Window{41e9b980 u0 com.artifex.mupdfdemo/com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ChoosePDFActivity}
I/ActivityManager(  548): Process com.artifex.mupdfdemo (pid 2677) has died.
```

Comment: Can you edit the logcat output for the crash into your question?

Comment: Some code on line `60` in `ChoosePDFAdapter` is `null` and you are trying to access a method or property on it.

Comment: Yes I saw that but I can't see how it is related to my problem. Do you have the source code at hand? Here is the line 59 and 60 and it as nothing to do with the modifications I made: ChoosePDFItem item = mItems.get(position); ((TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(item.name);

Comment: Mabe I should have tagged mupdf first because it seems to be specific with this project more than a general java question.

Answer (score 0):

MuPDF is adding view on Relative Layout.If you want to change in  toolbar, you just change the button.xml file.(mButtonsView).

```
Code:

  RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
            layout.addView(mDocView);
            layout.addView(mButtonsView);// mButtonsView its a toolbar
```

The given below code  button.xml,I have changed it according to my requirement.i hope its help you.

```
Xml Code:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rl_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#067CFC">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_document_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                tools:text="DocumentName" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:id="@+id/ll_back"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/iv_back"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_back" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/ll_done"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/ic_done"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="17dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_done" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_more"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:id="@+id/ic_more"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/ic_mor_icon" />

            </LinearLayout>
          <!--  <ImageView
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:id="@+id/ic_more"
                android:layout_width="5dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_mor_icon" />-->

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/topBar0Main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true">

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/closeReader"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:onClick="OnCloseReaderButtonClick"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/moreButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/closeReader"
                    android:onClick="OnMoreButtonClick"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/moreButton"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:visibility="gone" />

                <!--
                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/searchButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/moreButton"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/search_document"
                                android:background="@drawable/button"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_search" />

                            <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/moreButton"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                android:contentDescription="@string/more"
                                android:background="@drawable/button"
                                android:onClick="OnMoreButtonClick"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_more" />
                -->
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>


        <ViewAnimator
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/switcher"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_marginTop="54dp"
                android:id="@+id/topBar1Search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/cancelSearch"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:onClick="OnCancelSearchButtonClick"
                    />

                <EditText
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/searchText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cancelSearch"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/searchBack"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:hint="@string/search"
                    android:singleLine="true" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/searchBack"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/searchForward"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/searchForward"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/topBar4More"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageButton
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/cancelMoreButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:onClick="OnCancelMoreButtonClick"
                    />

                <ImageButton
                    android:visibility="gone"
                    android:id="@+id/printButton"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"
                    android:padding="12dip"
                    android:onClick="OnPrintButtonClick"
                    />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </ViewAnimator>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_below="@+id/rl_toolbar"
            android:id="@+id/lowerButtons"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/PreviewBarHolder"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                >
            </FrameLayout>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pageNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/PreviewBarHolder"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textIsSelectable="false" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/info"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/PreviewBarHolder"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textIsSelectable="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>
```